# QT debugger skipping breakpoints

Tags: qt, debugging

I am very frustrated with QT. I cannot get it to debug appropriately. It will skip breakpoints. I am in debug mode, using debug window.I have cleaned the project, and removed all debug and release directories that were created. Using Fedora 21.

I am also very reluctant to leave QT because the built-in Vim-emulator in it is so clean. I have Googled the hell out of this problem but the suggestions give I have either tried without success or they are explained at a level of ability above my own.

In any case, does anyone know of the solution to this that is able to explain it in a manner which is easily followed? Or, if you know of any IDE (C++) out there that has a comparable Vim plug-in that would be awesome as well. Thanks for your time, apologies for my novice-ness.

```
rhurac ~/build-HashTable-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_GCC_64bit-Debug $ cat Makefile 

Makefile for building: HashTable
Generated by qmake (3.0) (Qt 5.5.0)
Project:  ../HashTable/HashTable.pro
Template: app
Command: /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/bin/qmake -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug -o Makefile ../HashTable/HashTable.pro
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with Qt but with the debugger (gdb?) incorrectly configured in environment you use. My overall experience with debugging Qt executable modules on Linux was productive. Just because you also want to take advantages of IDE: use Qt own Qt Creator and that most likely integrates gdb properly. If you in fact use Qt Creator but experience difficulties, mind gdb settings: [Configure Qt Creator to work with GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475837/configure-qt-creator-to-work-with-gdb).

And skipping breakpoints may also imply that you need to turn compiler optimizations off for your debug mode.

And for VIM mode in Qt Creator: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-editor-fakevim.html